# QEMU emulator window is not showing up

Tags: qemu, raspberry-pi-desktop

I am trying to run custom kernel on QEMU emulator version 2.11.0. Compilation done successfully but QEMU emulation window is not showing up.

Should I use different QEMU emulator version? I am on Ubuntu 16.04 OS.

I am using following command to start emulator:

`qemu-system-arm -m 256 -M raspi2 -serial stdio -kernel myos.elf`

My kernel code is as follows:

```
#include <stdint.h>

// Memory-Mapped I/O output
static inline void mmio_write(uint32_t reg, uint32_t data)
{
    *(volatile uint32_t*)reg = data;
}

// Memory-Mapped I/O input
static inline uint32_t mmio_read(uint32_t reg)
{
    return *(volatile uint32_t*)reg;
}

// Loop <delay> times in a way that the compiler won't optimize away
static inline void delay(int32_t count)
{
    asm volatile("__delay_%=: subs %[count], %[count], #1; bne __delay_%=\n"
            : "=r"(count): [count]"0"(count) : "cc");
}

enum
{
    // The GPIO registers base address.
    GPIO_BASE = 0x3F200000, // for raspi2 & 3, 0x20200000 for raspi1


    // The offsets for reach register.

    // Controls actuation of pull up/down to ALL GPIO pins.
    GPPUD = (GPIO_BASE + 0x94),

    // Controls actuation of pull up/down for specific GPIO pin.
    GPPUDCLK0 = (GPIO_BASE + 0x98),

    // The base address for UART.
    UART0_BASE = 0x3F201000, // for raspi2 & 3, 0x20201000 for raspi1

    // The offsets for reach register for the UART.
    UART0_DR     = (UART0_BASE + 0x00),
    UART0_RSRECR = (UART0_BASE + 0x04),
    UART0_FR     = (UART0_BASE + 0x18),
    UART0_ILPR   = (UART0_BASE + 0x20),
    UART0_IBRD   = (UART0_BASE + 0x24),
    UART0_FBRD   = (UART0_BASE + 0x28),
    UART0_LCRH   = (UART0_BASE + 0x2C),
    UART0_CR     = (UART0_BASE + 0x30),
    UART0_IFLS   = (UART0_BASE + 0x34),
    UART0_IMSC   = (UART0_BASE + 0x38),
    UART0_RIS    = (UART0_BASE + 0x3C),
    UART0_MIS    = (UART0_BASE + 0x40),
    UART0_ICR    = (UART0_BASE + 0x44),
    UART0_DMACR  = (UART0_BASE + 0x48),
    UART0_ITCR   = (UART0_BASE + 0x80),
    UART0_ITIP   = (UART0_BASE + 0x84),
    UART0_ITOP   = (UART0_BASE + 0x88),
    UART0_TDR    = (UART0_BASE + 0x8C),
};

void uart_init()
{
    // Disable UART0.
    mmio_write(UART0_CR, 0x00000000);
    // Setup the GPIO pin 14 && 15.

    // Disable pull up/down for all GPIO pins & delay for 150 cycles.
    mmio_write(GPPUD, 0x00000000);
    delay(150);

    // Disable pull up/down for pin 14,15 & delay for 150 cycles.
    mmio_write(GPPUDCLK0, (1 << 14) | (1 << 15));
    delay(150);

    // Write 0 to GPPUDCLK0 to make it take effect.
    mmio_write(GPPUDCLK0, 0x00000000);

    // Clear pending interrupts.
    mmio_write(UART0_ICR, 0x7FF);

    // Set integer & fractional part of baud rate.
    // Divider = UART_CLOCK/(16 * Baud)
    // Fraction part register = (Fractional part * 64) + 0.5
    // UART_CLOCK = 3000000; Baud = 115200.

    // Divider = 3000000 / (16 * 115200) = 1.627 = ~1.
    mmio_write(UART0_IBRD, 1);
    // Fractional part register = (.627 * 64) + 0.5 = 40.6 = ~40.
    mmio_write(UART0_FBRD, 40);

    // Enable FIFO & 8 bit data transmissio (1 stop bit, no parity).
    mmio_write(UART0_LCRH, (1 << 4) | (1 << 5) | (1 << 6));

    // Mask all interrupts.
    mmio_write(UART0_IMSC, (1 << 1) | (1 << 4) | (1 << 5) | (1 << 6) |
            (1 << 7) | (1 << 8) | (1 << 9) | (1 << 10));

    // Enable UART0, receive & transfer part of UART.
    mmio_write(UART0_CR, (1 << 0) | (1 << 8) | (1 << 9));
}

void uart_putc(unsigned char c)
{
    // Wait for UART to become ready to transmit.
    while ( mmio_read(UART0_FR) & (1 << 5) ) { }
    mmio_write(UART0_DR, c);
}

unsigned char uart_getc()
{
    // Wait for UART to have received something.
    while ( mmio_read(UART0_FR) & (1 << 4) ) { }
    return mmio_read(UART0_DR);
}

void uart_puts(const char* str)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i ++)
        uart_putc((unsigned char)str[i]);
}

#if defined(__cplusplus)
extern "C" /* Use C linkage for kernel_main. */
#endif
void kernel_main(uint32_t r0, uint32_t r1, uint32_t atags)
{
    // Declare as unused
    (void) r0;
    (void) r1;
    (void) atags;

    uart_init();
    uart_puts("Hello, kernel World!\r\n");

    while (1) {
        uart_putc(uart_getc());
        uart_putc('\n');
    }
}
```

As suggested in tutorial I am getting "Hello , kernel World" printed on terminal. but QEMU window is not showing up.

thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Could you add more details, perhaps list the commands you have used?

Comment: I added details. I am using following command to start emulator: "qemu-system-arm -m 256 -M raspi2 -serial stdio -kernel myos.elf". Please suggest if you need more details.